Encountered an unknown dumb error during Uniswap V3 contract swap invocation, completely clueless
I wrote a contract myself to perform a simple swap on the BSC testnet using Uniswap V3. Specifically, I want to swap WBNB for BUSD, and I have hardcoded the parameters for clarity. I assure that the contract holds sufficient tokens of "0xae13d989daC2f0dEbFf460aC112a837C89BAa7cd" (WBNB).
However, every time I execute the contract, it fails with an error, and no valuable error message is displayed. I am unsure where the problem lies.
Could you please help me identify and resolve this issue?
This is my own deployed contract at https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0x244b5b4b147ae4b2581cc98cf6e2d169c24ec257, and it holds sufficient WBNB tokens.

The address 0x994fA482580Fe98C53cF79be61768eb3d01795b8 is the trading pair for WBNB and BUSD.
The address 0xae13d989daC2f0dEbFf460aC112a837C89BAa7cd is the token address for WBNB.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import '../lib/interfaces/IUniswapV3Pool.sol';
import '../lib/interfaces/IERC20.sol';

contract TestV3Swap {
    constructor(){}

    function start() external {

        address pool = 0x994fA482580Fe98C53cF79be61768eb3d01795b8;
        address recipient = 0xD7Dd7BF70e6fe90F0A530aEb494fbe5536aBa48A;
        int256 amountSpecified = 100000000000000;
        uint160 sqrtPriceLimitX96 = 4295128740;
        bool zeroForOne = true;

        IUniswapV3Pool(pool).swap(
            recipient,
            zeroForOne,
            amountSpecified,
            sqrtPriceLimitX96,
            new bytes(0));
    }

    function uniswapV3SwapCallback(
        int256 amount0Delta,
        int256 amount1Delta,
        bytes calldata _data
    ) external {

        IERC20(0xae13d989daC2f0dEbFf460aC112a837C89BAa7cd).transfer(msg.sender, 100000000000000);

    }

}



IPancakeV3SwapCallback(msg.sender).pancakeV3SwapCallback(amount0, amount1, data);

You should implement pancakeV3SwapCallback() instead of uniswapV3SwapCallback().
success: https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x457ac08a0418a18a41efef15c24b3e6ce166127fc75ba41db6e771fca06d5d08


Haha, yes, thank you very much for your reminder. I really made a silly mistake.

After creating a pool on uniswapv3, you need to:

Initialize the pool.
Add liquidity for both the tokens (in your case WBNB and BUSD) through the NonFungiblePositionManagerContract.
Then make a swap.

It looks like you have missed these steps.
Also, if that doesn't help, you can try simulating your transaction on Tenderly. It will help you understand from where you are getting the error message.
Let me know if you have any questions. Feel free to mark this as answer if it helps.

It's really great. I tried using the tool you provided, Tenderly, and discovered that the issue was actually due to a typo in the callback function name. In PancakeSwap, it should be "pancakeV3SwapCallback" instead of "uniswapV3SwapCallback."
Thank you very much for providing this tool, I really like it.
